# WCF Duplex Is it possible to wait for callback to complete?

Tags: wcf

I am writing n duplex WCF application, just want to make sure that the client call must halt till callback method is complete.

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> just want to make sure that the client call must halt till callback
>   method is complete.

To my understanding, in that case, you don't need to employ `Duplex Communication` system. An singular `Request - Reply` communication system should suffice; which is by the way, is default communication mechanism.